# add a column that can separate the numeric values into low median and high segments?

Tags: python, pandas

```
number = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,20).reshape(20,1), columns=['Number to segement'])
```

How to add a column to its side that can divide the column into groups(<25%, 25%~75%, >75%) automatically according to its values to the column?

*Example:*

[image]

Comment: Add an example of input and intended output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.qcut` does pretty much exactly what you're looking for:

```
In [37]: number["quantile"] = pd.qcut(number["Number to segement"], [0, .25, .75, 1], labels=["<25%", "25-75%", ">75%"])

In [38]: number
Out[38]:
    Number to segement quantile
0                   53   25-75%
1                   85   25-75%
2                   95     >75%
3                   96     >75%
4                   60   25-75%
5                   37   25-75%
6                   32     <25%
7                   42   25-75%
8                   50   25-75%
9                   32     <25%
10                  30     <25%
11                  51   25-75%
12                  88     >75%
13                  76   25-75%
14                  10     <25%
15                  51   25-75%
16                  97     >75%
17                   1     <25%
18                  23     <25%
19                  87     >75%
```

If you leave out the labels argument, it returns the cutoff values instead if you'd prefer to see those.